# Local wamp64 server - wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I am usnig wamp server. I extracted the wordpress zip and named the folder myblogsite and kept insude te www folder of wamp in C drive.

Edited w-config.php and added database details, Authentication Unique Keys and salt details (generated random keys) . I have NOT added my website URl here.

Now I am trying to access http://localhost/myblogsite and http://localhost:8009/myblogsite – Both gives me error–“This site can’t be reached . localhost refused to connect.”

Tried accessing localhost:8009 – Gave me my folder structure in wamp/www . Tried clicking on myblogsite folder from here. This again gave me above error.

The config is like below

```
        /** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpressblog');

 /** MySQL database username */
 define('DB_USER', 'wordpressusername');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'L|P$sb-]hS(:hk]r+34UVxgH[|y~Q^KWz^3-U(bkjm91ki| ,9q(VU*rROf^N L)');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'n?UC)5&Z>;;&3q1kZ[!GQ;k}|7#RY #8c-f0yLzg62r3Pz)/`_jh$d|;p*zJ(LU2');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '^raQ^9{siV)[L>o1>i~?hg[G%y}fY U5buOirr)-hEziUj]+ZKHuN}6m4Pn@0dx+');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '4&:0_BRK9}y7f-bJ1z/7Y|j;-D,[-+iaHG$>]c,-g& M+]2+bZYjsHe|I-3ymU@K');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'Y-?~5u%?/i0OV}KrMd;b0|/MNic3ufAPCHJRYEMY94BOu)#(1^~B/JHAdL8JuXZV');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '7,3Xv/[koEq7EGldx8/oy*}NH$MEB=%Qo8LNoPxM4h-<^KE6B7wj0#D28h6JHe!B');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   ',^ 85HPt{l;*jPSA+e>}Ol+<Mle|e|/A-}H~6tO<m3#;$IP7aAvP@)uulCN_:=]W');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '^-v{< z[Lypy-m|%uiKR%1d,|sY+>AnL`*amg0?JQ,*55/kZJU;[ZB+NQE-q(;;q');
/**#@-*/
```

Edit: Flashback- 
I had successfully installed wordpress once. Was able to access my site via localhost/wp-admin.php OR localhost/wp-login.php. Then I changed my site URL in the settings tab of wordpress site. From then it started to redirect the URL in loop and fail. Then I deleted the wordpress folder from www and added it again and that lead to my current problem. now localost/wp-admin.php gives me a message "already installed" with a link to log in which lands me into a page cannot be accessed page

Comment: Why are you using port 8009?

Comment: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295

Comment: And [The need for Virtual hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: port I can change in httpd.config. I can try without the port number if its default portnumber 80.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I successfully installed wordpress once. Was able to access my site via localhost/wp-admin.php  OR localhost/wp-login.php.
Then I changed my site URL in the settings tab of wordpress site. From then it started to redirect the URL in loop and fail. Then I deleted the wordpress folder from www and added it again and that lead to my current problem. 

now localost/wp-admin.php gives me a message "already installed" with a link to log in which lands me into a page cannot be accessed page

Comment: did a clean re -install . Worked but still struggling with theme change issues